# 'You do not have access to the directory specified for this field' issue with MSM

Tags: file-uploads, multi-site-manager

I am using MSM to create multiple sites on an EE project. When I create a new site I copy over all the channels/entries from my default site.

When I go in to add/edit an entry all my file uploads say 'You do not have access to the directory specified for this field'.

To fix this I can go to the field settings and change 'Allowed directory' from 'All > Uploads'.

However this is fairly time consuming as I have lots of file type fields. Is there any other way I can make this work without changing the above? Or when I create the new site have them set to 'uploads' which is how they are on the default site?

Cheers
Darren